# Phing SSH Agent forwarding

Tags: ssh, phing

Phing running on Server A, with this SSH task to connect to server B:

```
<ssh username="xxxxxx"
host="B"
pubkeyfile="/home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
privkeyfile="/home/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pem"
command="cd ./public_html/staging; hg pull />
```

It connects to server B ok, but the `hg pull` which tries to connect to server C spits back `remote: Permission denied (public key)`.

However manually SSH'ing into server B from A and doing an `hg pull` works fine, suggesting Agent Forwarding is working as I'm not running any agent on B, only on A.

Is there a way I can see which public key is indeed being used by B to try to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like agent forwarding is not supported by PHP's SSH2 which Phing's  task uses.

Replacing the `<ssh>` task with a simple exec task, i.e.,

`<exec command="ssh xxxxxx@B 'cd ./public_html/staging; hg pull'"/>`

did the trick.