# Unable to run ssh command using phing exec tag

Tags: ssh, phing

I have the following exec tag in my build xml file -

```
<exec "ssh ${sshUserName}@${sshHost} 'ls -l'" outputProperty="fileListTemp" dir="." />
```

Running the build gives me error on this line -

```
BUILD FAILED
/mnt/home/sandeepan/test_phing_build/build.xml:83:15: > required
```

I am not able to understand the error.

*Note - I am not using the SshTask because I do not have PHP SSH2 extension installed, and I am not installing it because I don't know whether I actually need it.*

I followed the syntax given in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21427332/351903

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid XML. You're missing the attribute name for your command. It's either `command` or `executable` according to the [documentation](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/ExecTask.html).

**command:**

```xml
<exec
    command="ssh ${sshUserName}@${sshHost} 'ls -l'"
    outputProperty="fileListTemp"
    dir="."
/>
```

**executable:**

```xml
<exec executable="ssh" outputProperty="fileListTemp" dir=".">
    <arg value="${sshUserName}@${sshHost}" />
    <arg value="ls -l" />
</exec>
```

I'd also recommend using the `checkreturn` switch (`checkreturn="true"`) to let the build fail if the command failed.